# Solving coefficient sum constrained elastic net with quadratic objective term

Tags: regularization, elastic-net, constrained-optimization

I am looking for an algorithm to solve an equality constrained elastic net. 
There are two adaptations I need to make to the standard elastic net. First the objective function includes a quadratic term, and second the sum of my coefficients is constrained to be equal to one. 
My objective function would be:

minimize $\quad x^TAx + \lambda \; (\alpha ||x||_1 + (1- \alpha ) ||x||_2^2)  $ 
subject to $ \ \ \sum_{i=1}^N x_i = 1  $

Comment: If x is real, then R package nloptr could be used: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/nloptr.pdf